# Best way to organize sql DB for a forum site

Tags: mysql

I'm a total beginner in SQL databases and I'm not sure on how to organize the databases and tables for this website I'm making as a trimester project.

The website is a 4chan-like forum site, but instead of having a separate directory for each board I have all boards that begin with a letter listed under that letter's directory.

E.g.

```
A boards -> art (artwork), ani (animation), etc.
```

As of now I've separated all letter directories (A boards, B boards) into their own DB and have tables for the files and posts submitted to each board in the DB.

'Posts' table stores the name, subject, comment and timestamp of each post.

'Files' table stores all info related to the uploaded files.

E.g.

```
A boards (DB)
 Tables:
  ani_posts (posts submitted to ani),
  ani_files (files submitted to ani),
  #_posts,
  #_files
```

and so on for each category (B boards, C boards, etc.) I associate files with posts using a foreign key and 'file_id'.

Is this a good method? How can it be improved?

Comment: I would use one table for all posts, and then have a column for the particular subject.  Not sure if this is what you did.  Then there is the question of how many posts you expect per day.

Comment: That's been on my mind lately as well. Would I need to create the subject column in both the posts and the files table? The file_id is unique and on auto_increment. I don't expect many posts per day, my audience will be my school which is ~500 people.

Comment: The files table should have a foreign key pointing to the posts table (so you can link each file with a post).

Comment: Just to clarify, how often should I be making a new DB? For every domain? Every letter? Every category? What is the common practice? Same for tables?

Comment: For your use case, only one database and only create tables as you need them.

Comment: Thanks, I will post an answer in a few hours, re-writing sql and php...

Comment: And properly tag this thing as mysql or sql-server, not both

Comment: If your tired, maybe you should go to bed and try again tomorrow with a fresh head .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not posting earlier, some things came up.

I've remade the tables and DB so that all of the data is stored in a single DB. I've made a table titled "posts" and another "files".

Here is [a link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jjuelrlf7_HKxKfU0omjGQzID7-dCkBtDXPOvrJnPRU/edit?usp=sharing) to the spreadsheet with the table setup.

The posts table and files table are linked with a foreign key and cascading updates (posts table is parent). I pass the category abbreviation (art - artwork, ani - animation, etc.) to be stored on "posts" in order to place all posts on a single table.

Thanks to Tim Biegeleisen for raising the issue of traffic, but I think the server will handle ~500 posts on single table (that is if everyone posts on a daily basis).

I'm marking this question as answered, but am still open to optimization and advice.